# Orchard Module only shows Media Library items to logged in users

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

I created a very simple module that displays images in a specific folder in the Media Library. It works great when I'm logged in to my Orchard site, but the images are not displayed to anonymous users. Here is a simplified version of my module code:

```
public ActionResult Image(int id, int? width, int? height) {
        var items = _mediaLibraryService
                                       .GetMediaContentItems("Portfolio", 0, Int32.MaxValue, null, null);
        var mediaItem = items.Where(i => i.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();

        if (mediaItem == null) {
            return null;
        }

        string imageFileName = Server.MapPath(mediaItem.MediaUrl);
        string contentType = "image/" + Path.GetExtension(imageFileName).Substring(1);

        // code to resize image based on given parameters ...

        return File(imageFileName, contentType);
}
```

The action accepts the MediaPart id and dimensions, finds the item by id, resizes the image, and returns it as a FileResult. This works fine when logged in, but anonymous users get nothing. Looking in the network tab in Chrome, it shows that the response length is 0.

Of course, I don't get this behavior when testing locally, only on my live site. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your controller marked with the `[Admin]` attribute? Apart from that, there are a few problems with this code. First, Orchard already has image re-dimensioning capabilities, so it's not clear why you'd want to do that at all. Second, taking image dimensions as parameters of the action is dangerous: it's trivial to overload it with requests for very large images and take the server down.

Comment: No, there is no Admin attribute. I just discovered the Orchard's image re-dimensioning capabilities, I'll look into that. This is my first module.

Comment: I attempted to upgrade Orchard to 8 and failed, so I ended up abandoning it for now and rewrote the site in MVC. I'll have to attempt this again once I get better feel for the Orchard dev/testing environment.

Comment: In order to upgrade your own module to 1.8, you need to edit the web.config to set it to framework 4.5 and edit the cs.proj to set it too to 4.5